# Connect dropdown links to specific tabs

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am trying to connect links in a dropdown menu to a page with tabs, connecting their respective links to their respective tabs. Right now, the page that contains the dropdown menu and the page that contains the tabs are in separate HTML pages and have their own `ng-controller`.

header_view.html

```
<div role="navigation" ng-controller="HeaderController" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html" class="nav navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top ng-cloak">
    <li class="mobile-hide dropdown">
        <a href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle usermenu">
            {{model.firstname}}
            <div class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down small ml"></div>
        </a>
        <ul role="menu" class="dropdown-menu">
            <li class="arrow"></li>
            <li role="menuitem">
                <a href="#" ng-click="userPrefs()">Personal Information<div class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></div></a>
                    <div class="subtext">Update your email, phone number and mailing addresses.</div>
            </li>
            <hr class="divider"/>
            <li role="menuitem">
            <a href="#" ng-click="userPrefs()">Sign In & Security<div class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></div></a>
                <div class="subtext">Update your username, password and security question.</div>
            </li>
            <hr class="divider"/>
            <li role="menuitem"><a href="#" ng-click="userPrefs()">Account Preferences<div class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></div></a>
                <div class="subtext">Indicate your email and postal mail preferences.</div>
            </li>
            <div href="" ng-click="signout()" class="signout text-center">Sign Out</div>
        </ul>
    </li>
</div>
```

header.controller.js

```
angular.module('ogn.navTop').controller('HeaderController', ['$scope',
        function($scope) {
            $scope.userPrefs = function() {
                        console.log('ENV.name' + ENV.name);
                        $window.location.href = 'userprefs.html';
                    };
        }
]);
```

subnav.html

```
<div ng-controller="UserprefsController" class="subnav-tabs">
    <tabset>
        <tab ng-repeat="tab in tabs" heading="{{tab.title}}" active="tab.active">
            <ng-include src="tab.content"></ng-include>
        </tab>
    </tabset>
</div>
```

userprefs.controller.js

```
angular.module('ogn.userprefs').controller('UserprefsController', ['$scope',
    function($scope) {
        $scope.tabs = [
            { title: 'Personal Information', content: 'modules/userprefs/views/personalinfo.html'},
            { title: 'Sign In & Security', content: 'modules/userprefs/views/signin_security.html'},
            { title: 'Account Preferences', content: 'modules/userprefs/views/accountprefs.html'}
        ];
}]);
```

Is it recommended to put a controller into another controller (or would that even work)? How can I connect the dropdown links to the tabs if the page doesn't know the controller that can be used to call the tabs? I need to do this in pure Angular if possible. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Off topic: An `<hr>` is not a valid child of a `<ul>`. Nor is a div.

Comment: I know, but we are using Jade and it doesn't conflict with anything else. It's for UI purposes

Comment: That's a pretty low bar for coding standards. Anyway, you'd use a service to track and update the tabs. Services connect controllers.

Comment: IMO, services don't do a great job of this, mainly because they can't have bindable properties, so everyone has to spend a lot of energy trying to figure out when to call functions to update the data. I might be tempted to build it as a pair of directives that are embedded in the same View with a Controller at the top. If they edit the data, really the Controller isn't doing much but hosting the data that both directives are plugged into. Of course, the directives would have their own controllers, so technically you'd still have controllers in a view controlled by a controller.

Comment: To @Isherwood 's comment, I agree that the better way to style this is to use css on the li's. And then you could just use the same collection to drive both the menu and the tabs with an ng-repeat, setting the "active" property on the selected menu item.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a simple case of nested views. I recommend to use the angular ui router plugin to handle all routing. It handles routing very elegant, gives you a lot of posibilities and your links will be nothing but a state from now on.

See more on the [Angular UI Router GitHub page](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router).

With this properly setup you create links to views with the `ui-sref` directive so a link in one of your dropdowns will become:

```
<a ui-sref="mainState">Go to main view</a>
<a ui-sref="mainState.subTab1">Go to main view and tab 1</a>
```

This makes it much simpler to read the html and deeplinking comes with it.